# High concurrent Apache HTTP Server SSL issues

Tags: java, ssl, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a HTTP server application which is working normally under normal HTTP traffic(~10k requests/sec) but when the traffic gets heavier it starts be unresponsive for a period(~30 sec to 1 minute) without any AV or any other clues to indicate the problem. After this time it's recovering and start to work normally until is 'sleeping' again. From app logs, the problem seems to be on the SSL traffic, after making the SSL handshake it takes several seconds to send the next packages to a HAProxy when my server is responsive:

[image]

and more than 30 sec when server is unresponsive(in this case 1 min and a half):

[image]

How I'm creating the connection pool:

```
//create the SSL Context for the connection factory
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try{
            sslContext=SSLContext.getDefault();                            
            
    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }         

    BasicNIOConnFactory connFactory=new BasicNIOConnFactory(sslContext,null,ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);

    clientConnectionPool=new BasicNIOConnPool(requestsReactor,connFactory,0);
    clientConnectionPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(30000);
    clientConnectionPool.setMaxTotal(30000);
```

and a HttpAsyncRequester client which is forwarding the request to the HAProxy:

```
private HttpAsyncRequester initializeHttpClientForCalls(final ConnectingIOReactor ioReactor)
            throws IOReactorException {
        // Create HTTP protocol processing chain
        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
                // Use standard client-side protocol interceptors
                .add(new RequestContent(true)).
                 add(new RequestTargetHost()).
                 add(new RequestConnControl())
                .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).
                 build();

        // Create HTTP requester
        HttpAsyncRequester requester = new HttpAsyncRequester(httpproc);
        // Create client-side HTTP protocol handler
        HttpAsyncRequestExecutor protocolHandler = new HttpAsyncRequestExecutor();
        // Create client-side I/O event dispatch
        final IOEventDispatch ioEventDispatch =
                new DefaultHttpClientIODispatch<>(protocolHandler, ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
 
        // Run the I/O reactor in a separate thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Ready to go!
                    ioReactor.execute(ioEventDispatch);
                } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
                    logger.error("Interrupted", ex);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("I/O error", e);
                }
                 catch (Exception e){
                     logger.error("Exception encountered in Client ", e.getMessage(), e);
                 }
                logger.info("Client calls shutdown");
            }

        }, "Client for calls").start();
        return requester;
    }
```

And the call:

```
    clientRequester.execute(new BasicAsyncRequestProducer(httpHost, request), new BasicAsyncResponseConsumer(),
            clientConnectionPool, coreContext,
            // Handle HTTP response from a callback
            new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
```

IOReactors have 16 threads assigned. Increasing the threads number does not improve the performance

```
            IOReactorConfig requestsConfig = IOReactorConfig.
                    custom().
//                  setSoLinger(0).
                    setSoReuseAddress(true).
                    setIoThreadCount(16).
                    build();

            // Create server-side I/O reactor
            requestsIoReactor = new DefaultListeningIOReactor(requestsConfig);
```

Connecting with Java VisualVM on the server where app is deployed and running a batch of aprox 400 SSL requests against the app show that no custom processing of the requests are time penalty:

[image]

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

with latest org.apache.httpcomponents.

I know this question [Highly Concurrent Apache Async HTTP Client IOReactor issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180877/highly-concurrent-apache-async-http-client-ioreactor-issues) and read probably all the questions on this topic, but it does not provide a solution to my issue. Is there a way to improve the SSL performance?

Comment: Is this question about the *Apache Commons HTTP* implementation used in the code that you post? If yes, please tag accordingly: [tag:apache] is about Apache *httpd*. If your question is indeed about Apache httpd, it seems to be configuration related and a better fit for serverfault than stackoverflow (see the [tag:apache] tag description). (i.e. question title talks about "Apache HTTP server", but the question talks about haproxy)

Comment: There are too many moving parts. Is there any chance you could reproduce this issue with a standalone test application?